# outputText not calling backing bean method

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I'm trying to implement an instant row selection on a PrimeFaces 4 datatable that pops up a dialog with details from the selected row.

The relevant code snippets are:

Datatable:

```
<p:dataTable id="Table" 
    var="user" rowKey="#{user.id}" 
    selection="#{userDAO.selectedComplaintRow}" 
    selectionMode="single" value="#{userDAO.complaintList}" 
    style="font-size:10px;">
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{userDAO.onRowSelect}" 
    update=":form:Table, :form:messages" 
    oncomplete="PF('showComplaint').show()" />
...
```

Dialog:

```
<p:dialog header="Details" widgetVar="showComplaint"
    id="dialog" resizable="false" width="400" showEffect="explode"
    modal="true" hideEffect="explode">

    <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5">
        <h:outputText value="Forename: " />  
        <h:outputText value="#{userDAO.selectedComplaintRow.getForename()}" />

    </h:panelGrid>
</p:dialog>
```

UserDAO.onRowSelect():

```
public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {  
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("User Selected", "Selected!");  

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
}
```

UserDAO getter and setter:

```
public void setSelectedComplaintRow(User selectedComplaintRow) {  
    this.selectedComplaintRow = selectedComplaintRow;  
    System.out.println("Passed forename: " + this.selectedComplaintRow.getForename());
} 

public User getSelectedComplaintRow() { 
    System.out.println("Retrieved forename: " + this.selectedComplaintRow.getForename());
    return this.selectedComplaintRow;  
}
```

User getter and setter:

```
public String getForename() {
    return this.forename;
}

public void setForename(String forename) {
    this.forename = forename;
}
```

While the (old-school) `System.out.println()` gets the forename successfully from the User entity bean and prints it to the Eclipse console, when the dialog opens, the space to the right of "Forename: " is blank as if null were passed by `#{userDAO.selectedComplaintRow.getForename()}` binding.

Both datatable and dialog are within the same  tags.

What might be causing this?

Comment: BTW, the bean is @ViewScoped

Comment: I've also tried 
<h:outputText value="#{userDAO.selectedComplaintRow.forename}" />
with the same results.

Comment: Is your setSelectedComplaintRow() method called at all? Where is the h:form tag?

Comment: Both `setSelectedComplaintRow()` and `getSelectedComplaintRow()` are called. The `<h:form>` tag is before the `<p:datatable>` tag and the `</h:form>` is after the `</p:dialog>` tag. I'm not nesting form tags, btw.

Comment: When are they called? If the ajax event calls them you might need to update contents of the dialog too. The PF.show() method is client only and displays the dialog as it was rendered on page load. Try with update=":form" if dialog is in same form.

Comment: That did the trick! I added `update=":form:dialog"` to the `onRowSelect` ajax call as follows: `<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{bigComplaintsDAO.onRowSelect}" update=":form:ComplaintTable, :form:messages, :form:dialog" oncomplete="PF('showComplaint').show()" />`. Many thanks, @scraatz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I did as @scraatz suggested and added `update=":form:dialog"` to the `rowSelect` ajax event as below:

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{bigComplaintsDAO.onRowSelect}" 
    update=":form:ComplaintTable, :form:messages, :form:dialog" 
    oncomplete="PF('showComplaint').show()" />
```

This appears to update the dialog after the data has been passed to it, whereas without this, the dialog is loaded before any data is passed to it and is not updated when the data is subsequently passed to it by `#{userDAO.selectedComplaintRow.forename}`.